# tf.get_collection to extract variables of one scope

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have `n` (e.g: n=3) scopes and `x` (e.g: x=4) no of Variables defined in each scope.
The scopes are:

```
model/generator_0
model/generator_1
model/generator_2
```

Once I compute the loss, I want to extract and provide all the variables from only one of the scope based on a criteria during run-time. Hence the index of the scope `idx` that I select is an argmin tensor cast into int32

```
<tf.Tensor 'model/Cast:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

I have already tried:

```
train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'model/generator_'+tf.cast(idx, tf.string))
```

which obviously did not work.
Is there any way to get all the `x` Variables belonging to that particular scope using idx to pass into the optimizer.

Thanks in advance!

Vignesh Srinivasan

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this in TF 1.0 rc1 or later:

```
v = tf.Variable(tf.ones(()))
loss = tf.identity(v)
with tf.variable_scope('adamoptim') as vs:
   optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)
optim_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=vs.name)
print([v.name for v in optim_vars]) #=> prints lists of vars created
```

Comment: unfortunately, the optim_vars contains all the variables from all the scopes. My problem is that I have 
~
    with tf.variable_scope('generator_0'):
        v1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones(()))
        loss1 = tf.identity(v1)

    with tf.variable_scope('generator_1'):
        v2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones(()))
        loss2 = tf.identity(v2)
~
I then want to find the tf.minimum(loss, loss2) and pass the variables belonging to that loss to the optimizer.

Comment: I just tested it in latest version (nightly) and `optim_vars` only contains variables from `adapoptim` scope

Comment: You are using the same loss defined, which I do not know before-hand. I have to find the  `min_idx = tf.cast(tf.argmin(tf.stack([loss1,loss2]) , 0), tf.int32)` and then pass this `loss = tf.stack([loss1,loss2])[min_idx]` to the optimizer. And that is why I am getting all the variables defined by using ur suggestion.

Comment: You could restructure your code to create separate optimizer for each loss, that might make it easier

Comment: Yes, I could do that. In that case, all the optimizers will be executed at run time. 
I would like to execute only that optimizer belonging to the generator with the least loss. 
In the meantime, I also tried `tf.stack([optim1, optim2])` , which also failed.

Comment: The problem is similar to the mixture of experts, where one would not want to run all the `n` models but train only a few(one in my case) where the loss is less. Do you think this question will be a better fit in the tensorflow issues ?