# Mixture of experts - Train best model only at each iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a crude method based on the Mixture-of-Experts paper in **tensorflow** - `https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06538`

There would be `n` models defined:

```
    model_1:
        var_11
        var_12
        loss_1
        optimizer_1

    model_2:
        var_21
        var_22
        loss_2
        optimizer_2

    model_3:
        var_31
        var_32
        loss_3
        optimizer_3
```

At every iteration, I want to train the model with the least loss only while keeping the other variables constant. Is it possible to place a switch to execute one of the optimizer only?

P.S: This base of this problem is similar to one I had asked previously. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073239/tf-get-collection-to-extract-variables-of-one-scope/42074009?noredirect=1#comment71359330_42074009`

Since the suggestion there did not work, I am trying to approach the problem differently.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be doable with `tf.cond`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_conditional_train_op(
    should_update, optimizers, variable_lists, losses):
  """Conditionally trains variables.

  Each argument is a Python list of Tensors, and each list must have the same
  length. Variables are updated based on their optimizer only if the
  corresponding `should_update` boolean Tensor is True at a given step.

  Returns a single train op which performs the conditional updates.
  """
  assert len(optimizers) == len(variable_lists)
  assert len(variable_lists) == len(losses)
  assert len(should_update) == len(variable_lists)
  conditional_updates = []
  for model_number, (update_boolean, optimizer, variables, loss) in enumerate(
      zip(should_update, optimizers, variable_lists, losses)):
    conditional_updates.append(
        tf.cond(update_boolean,
                lambda: tf.group(
                    optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=variables),
                    tf.Print(0, ["Model {} updating".format(model_number), loss])),
                lambda: tf.no_op()))
  return tf.group(*conditional_updates)
```

The basic strategy is to make sure the optimizer's variable updates are defined in the `lambda` of one of the `cond` branches, in which case there is true conditional op execution, meaning that the assignment to variables (and optimizer accumulators) only happens if that branch of the `cond` is triggered.

As an example, we can construct some models:

```
def make_model_and_optimizer():
  scalar_variable = tf.get_variable("scalar", shape=[])
  vector_variable = tf.get_variable("vector", shape=[3])
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(scalar_variable * vector_variable)
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1)
  return optimizer, [scalar_variable, vector_variable], loss

# Construct each model
optimizers = []
variable_lists = []
losses = []
for i in range(10):
  with tf.variable_scope("model_{}".format(i)):
    optimizer, variables, loss = make_model_and_optimizer()
  optimizers.append(optimizer)
  variable_lists.append(variables)
  losses.append(loss)
```

Then determine a conditional update strategy, in this case only training the model with the maximum loss (just because that results in more switching; the output is rather boring if only one model ever updates):

```
# Determine which model should be updated (in this case, the one with the
# maximum loss)
integer_one_hot = tf.one_hot(
    tf.argmax(tf.stack(losses),
              axis=0),
    depth=len(losses))
is_max = tf.equal(
    integer_one_hot,
    tf.ones_like(integer_one_hot))
```

Finally, we can call the `make_conditional_train_op` function to create the train op, then do some training iterations:

```
train_op = make_conditional_train_op(
    tf.unstack(is_max), optimizers, variable_lists, losses)

# Repeatedly call the conditional train op
with tf.Session():
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  for i in range(20):
    print("Iteration {}".format(i))
    train_op.run()
```

This is printing the index which is updated and its loss at each iteration, confirming the conditional execution:

```
Iteration 0
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Model 6 updating][2.7271919]
Iteration 1
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Model 6 updating][2.1755948]
Iteration 2
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Model 2 updating][1.9858969]
Iteration 3
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [Model 6 updating][1.6859927]
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: how would you apply this to a batch?

Comment: That's easy enough to do for something like a pure gradient descent optimizer (find the min, then `tf.gather` just that part of the batch when computing the loss that gets optimized). The issue is for optimizers like Adam which have momentum updates; there I don't know of any general way without diving into the optimizer's implementation. You may want to start a new question with more details about what you're looking to do (and feel free to ping me about it if you don't get an answer).